# Script tag with charset dynamically added to Unicode-header page is not processed properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, unicode, cross-domain

In PHP, I have a page whose header is set as **unicode**. (*not* through meta-tags. **I have PHP setting the charset to UTF-8**.)

After the page is displayed, I need to dynamically add a `<script>` tag that refers to another domain's code.

While the cross-domain Javascript already referred to in the HTML of the page gets parsed properly, the dynamically-added remote Javascript "Charset" is ignored.

Ergo, two JS files from the same domain get interpreted very differently.  The one that was already loaded into the HTML gets processed properly, but the one that's dynamically added is processed incorrectly... Even though I'm supplying the proper charset.

**Here's my example code:**

```
$('#footer').after( $('<script>').attr('type','text/javascript').attr('charset','ISO-8859-1').attr('src','//remoteJavascript.js') );
```

I'm also using jQuery 1.6.2.

Comment: It's interesting that this isn't working for you (for me, it works as long as I set `charset` before `src`), but in general the `script charset` attribute is not reliably supported cross-browser in any case. Getting a script to execute using a different charset to the one the parent page is in is annoying and inconsistent; it's almost always better to change the script so it matches encoding or doesn't rely on raw non-ASCII characters.

Comment: In the end, I blamed Chrome, and made my site deliver content in the standard ISO.  Kinda a pain-- means I'll have to remove any unicode characters.

Comment: You can still use non-ASCII characters in JS string literals using `\u` escapes, so it's not usually a problem.